Issue Controlling Label Font Size on xAxis in LightningChartJS with React and TypeScript
I'm currently working on a project using React with TypeScript and LightningChartJS. I'm trying to place some custom text directly underneath the x-axis labels so that it appears as part of the axis, fitting perfectly beneath the x-axis numbers.
According to the LightningChartJS documentation, there should be a function to control the label font size. However, when I try to use this function, TypeScript throws an error saying that it doesn't exist.

error from code sandbox:

link to code sandbox:
https://5f65cx.csb.app/
Here are the details:
LightningChartJS version: 6.0.2
Package: @lightningchart/lcjs: ^6.0.2
Problem Details:
Expected Behavior: I should be able to control the font size of the x-axis labels and add custom text below the axis that fits neatly with the existing labels.
Actual Behavior: TypeScript compiler reports that the method to control the label font size does not exist.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve this? Is there an alternative approach to add custom text beneath the x-axis labels?
images:




Try this code:
axisX2
  .addCustomTick()
  .setValue(9.0)
  .setTextFormatter((value) => `Notes`)
  .setTickLabelRotation(270)
  .setGridStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
  .setMouseInteractions(false)
  .setTickLabelPadding(-10)
  .setMarker((tickMarker) =>
    tickMarker.setTextFont((font) => font.setSize(10)).setEffect(false)
  );


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
